# How should I modify str.replace_all?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I recently discovered how to use str.replace_all . And again the question arose.

```
    useentryalert = input(defval=true, title="Use Entry Alert", group="Alert Messages")
    entrystring = input.text_area(title="Entry Alert Message", defval='TVM:{"exchange":"binance-futures","account":"*","symbol":"@@@/USDT", "type":"market","side":"buy","amount":{{entrySize}},"token":"1234"}:MVT', confirm=false, group="Alert Messages")
    
    alertMsg1 = str.replace_all(entrystring, "{{entrySize}}", str.tostring(entry_size))

    if entry condition
         strategy.order("Short", strategy.short, qty=entry_size, limit=r_close, comment="Entry", alert_message=alertMsg1)
```

I would like to create one more variable while modifying the message I put in the entrystring's defval.

Previously, only {{entrySize}} was entered, but I would like to include {{tp_price}} along with it.

```
TVM:{"exchange":"binance-futures","account":"*","symbol":"@@@/USDT","type":"market","side":"buy","amount":{{entrySize}},","tp_price":{{tp_price}},"tp_lo_price":{{tp_price}},"token":"1234"}:MVT
```

If alertMsg1 contains {{entrySize}} and {{tp_price}}, how can I modify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add another `str.replace_all` call:

```
useentryalert = input(defval=true, title="Use Entry Alert", group="Alert Messages")
entrystring = input.text_area(title="Entry Alert Message", defval='TVM:{"exchange":"binance-futures","account":"*","symbol":"@@@/USDT", "type":"market","side":"buy","amount":{{entrySize}},"token":"1234"}:MVT', confirm=false, group="Alert Messages")
    
alertMsg1 = str.replace_all(entrystring, "{{entrySize}}", str.tostring(entry_size))

alertMsg1 := str.replace_all(alertMsg1, "{{tp_price}}", str.tostring(tp_price))

if entry condition
    strategy.order("Short", strategy.short, qty=entry_size, limit=r_close, comment="Entry", alert_message=alertMsg1)
```